# Encounter "fatal error - NtCreateEvent(lock): 0xC0000077" when execute kinit in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, kerberos

I have `mintty 1.2-beta1(x86_64-pc-cygwin)` installed on my Windows 7 64 bit.
Then I installed `krb5-workstation` version 1.12.1-2 to cygwin using `Cygwin Net Release Setup Program`.

But when I execute `kinit` or `klist` in cygwin, I got an error:

```
$ kinit
      1 [main] kinit 3912 C:\cygwin64\bin\kinit.exe: *** fatal error - NtCreateEvent(lock): 0xC0000077
Hangup
```

Restarting cygwin or restarting windows didn't work either.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when starting xterm, which just appears to flash briefly, then exit producing an xterm.exe.stackdump file.  If you give xterm the -hold option you will see the NtCreateEvent error.  The root cause of my problem was interference from AVG anti virus, and adding c:\cygwin64\bin\xterm.exe to AVG's exception list made xterm work again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it helps, but I had the same error code when I was trying to install CPANminus in Cygwin 64-bit. However the installation worked fine in the 32-bit version. It's not a full solution, but maybe you can try the 32-bit version of Cygwin.

Comment: You mean try the 32bit version on 64bit Windows?

Comment: yup exactly, am on windows 8, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run gdm3 on my Windows 7 desktop and ran into the same problems as you had. After some fiddeling, I got a working solution that I'm (very) happy with, so I wanted to share this with you. I did the following (you need to do this only *once*):

- Start the Cygwin Terminal (on your Windows PC)
- From the terminal, run `xlaunch.exe` and follow the dialogs (I ended up using XDMCP; a good article about configuring that can be found [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDM_XDMCP.html))
- Safe the resulting config file to your desktop

From now on, you can just click on the dekstop icon to launch the remote (gdm3) desktop.

Answer (score 0):

AVG seems to be causing the exception including a rsync.exe.stackdump.

If you get on the server side:

```
rsync: safe_read failed to read 1 bytes [Receiver]: Connection reset by peer (104)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(276) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

or client side:

```
rsync.exe  fatal error - NtCreateEvent(lock): 0xC0000058
```

try disabling AVG. If it works when disabled, I added the rsync.exe as an AVG program exception and rsync is fine again.